# VBA - Outlook Email.HTMLBody Line spacing?

Tags: email, vba, outlook, spacing

his is a small problem but is confusing me.  I am automating an email to be sent from excel.  The below code, for some reason, makes the last line have larger than normal spacing:

```
Sub emailspacing()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:14.5'>Thanks for your help</p>"
    .display
End With
```

Whereas, when I remove the P style part, the email is generated with perfect line spacing???

```
Sub emailspacing()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .HTMLBody = "Thanks for your help"
    .display
End With
```

Does anyone know a way to combine the stylised HTML text with normal line spacing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'spacing'?  I have no spacing after the last line (because it's the last line) and the spacing between the two lines is consistent for me (Outlook 2010).

Comment: Its clearer when the bottom line is highlighted.  when I do this the line is about 150% normal size.  I am adding extra pieces to the bottom via rangetohtml and the increased gap doesn't look right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cracked it!  This needed to be added to the p style:

margin-bottom:.0001pt;